# Add class to DIV element when quiz answer is correct or incorrect

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a CSS class to a JavaScript created element, but am experiencing a reference error for the `trackerMarker` element. The `tracker-marker` DIVs are displaying on load, but are undefined when used in conjunction with the event listener.

I have tried using the `createElement` function inside and outside of the `for loop`.

I am not sure where the issue is. I am learning JS as I go, so any tips or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```js
function answerTracker() {
  const answerTracker = document.querySelector(".tracker");
  let questions = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
  for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    let trackerMarker = document.createElement("div");
    trackerMarker.className = "tracker-marker";
    answerTracker.appendChild(trackerMarker);
  }
}

const runQuiz = (() => {
  // Generate tracker
  answerTracker();

  let answers = document.querySelectorAll(".radio");
  answers.forEach(function(answer) {
    answer.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let target = e.target;
      let container = target.closest(".container");
      let question = container.querySelector(".question");
      let next = container.querySelector("button");
      if (e.target.value == "t") {
        trackerMarker.classList.add("correct");
      } else {
        trackerMarker.classList.add("incorrect");
      }
      if (next !== null && next !== "") {
        next.style.display = "block";
      }
      question.style.display = "none";
    });
  });
})();
```

```css
.tracker {
  display: flex;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.tracker .tracker-marker {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  margin: 0 1.25rem;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.tracker .tracker-marker.correct {
  background-color: blue;
}

.question {
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.question .question__label {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tracker">
</div>

<fieldset class="container">
  <div class="question">
    <div class="question__label">
      <span class="question-marker">1</span>
      <label class="formControlLabel">Question One</label>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="t" id="question-one0" class="radio">
    <label for="question-one0">Answer A</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="f" id="question-one1" class="radio">
    <label for="question-one1">Answer B</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="f" id="question-one2" class="radio">
    <label for="question-one2">Answer C</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="f" id="question-one3" class="radio">
    <label for="question-one3">Answer D</label>
    <button type="button" style="display: none;">Next</button>
  </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="container" style="display: none;">
  <div class="question">
    <div class="question__label">
      <span class="question-marker">2</span>
      <label class="formControlLabel">Question Two</label>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" value="t" id="question-two0" class="radio">
    <label for="question-two0">Answer A</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" value="f" id="question-two1" class="radio">
    <label for="question-two1">Answer B</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" value="f" id="question-two2" class="radio">
    <label for="question-two2">Answer C</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" value="f" id="question-two3" class="radio">
    <label for="question-two3">Answer D</label>
    <button type="button" style="display: none;">Next</button>
  </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="container" style="display: none;">
  <div class="question">
    <div class="question__label">
      <span class="question-marker">3</span>
      <label class="formControlLabel">Question Three</label>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-three]" value="t" id="question-three0" class="radio">
    <label for="question-three0">Answer A</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-three]" value="f" id="question-three1" class="radio">
    <label for="question-three1">Answer B</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-three]" value="f" id="question-three2" class="radio">
    <label for="question-three2">Answer C</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-three]" value="f" id="question-three3" class="radio">
    <label for="question-three3">Answer D</label>
    <button type="button" style="display: none;">Next</button>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: You never set `trackerMarker` inside `runQuiz`

Comment: indeed, what is `tracerMarker`?

Answer (score 0):

You never set `trackerMarker` inside `runQuiz`.

I used [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) (because how you wrote your code) which will return an array of items which is not ideal. You should add an ID to your `trackerMarker` div and then use [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

```js
function answerTracker() {
  const answerTracker = document.querySelector(".tracker");
  let questions = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
  for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    let trackerMarker = document.createElement("div");
    trackerMarker.className = "tracker-marker";
    answerTracker.appendChild(trackerMarker);
  }
}

const runQuiz = (() => {
  // Generate tracker
  answerTracker();

  let answers = document.querySelectorAll(".radio");
  answers.forEach(function(answer) {
    answer.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let target = e.target;
      let container = target.closest(".container");
      let question = container.querySelector(".question");
      let next = container.querySelector("button");
      let trackerMarker = document.getElementsByClassName('tracker-marker')[0];
      // ^-- I added this line only
      if (e.target.value == "t") {
        trackerMarker.classList.add("correct");
      } else {
        trackerMarker.classList.add("incorrect");
      }
      if (next !== null && next !== "") {
        next.style.display = "block";
      }
      question.style.display = "none";
    });
  });
})();
```

```css
.tracker {
  display: flex;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.tracker .tracker-marker {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  margin: 0 1.25rem;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.tracker .tracker-marker.correct {
  background-color: blue;
}

.question {
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.question .question__label {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tracker">
</div>

<fieldset class="container">
  <div class="question">
    <div class="question__label">
      <span class="question-marker">1</span>
      <label class="formControlLabel">Question One</label>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="t" id="question-one0" class="radio">
    <label for="question-one0">Answer A</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="f" id="question-one1" class="radio">
    <label for="question-one1">Answer B</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="f" id="question-one2" class="radio">
    <label for="question-one2">Answer C</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="f" id="question-one3" class="radio">
    <label for="question-one3">Answer D</label>
    <button type="button" style="display: none;">Next</button>
  </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="container" style="display: none;">
  <div class="question">
    <div class="question__label">
      <span class="question-marker">2</span>
      <label class="formControlLabel">Question Two</label>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" value="t" id="question-two0" class="radio">
    <label for="question-two0">Answer A</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" value="f" id="question-two1" class="radio">
    <label for="question-two1">Answer B</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" value="f" id="question-two2" class="radio">
    <label for="question-two2">Answer C</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" value="f" id="question-two3" class="radio">
    <label for="question-two3">Answer D</label>
    <button type="button" style="display: none;">Next</button>
  </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="container" style="display: none;">
  <div class="question">
    <div class="question__label">
      <span class="question-marker">3</span>
      <label class="formControlLabel">Question Three</label>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-three]" value="t" id="question-three0" class="radio">
    <label for="question-three0">Answer A</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-three]" value="f" id="question-three1" class="radio">
    <label for="question-three1">Answer B</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-three]" value="f" id="question-three2" class="radio">
    <label for="question-three2">Answer C</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="form[question-three]" value="f" id="question-three3" class="radio">
    <label for="question-three3">Answer D</label>
    <button type="button" style="display: none;">Next</button>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I adjusted my code to use your `ClassName` suggestion, but it only works on the first `tracker-marker` element. How can it be adapted to apply the class of **correct** or **incorrect** to each `tracker-marker` element depending on the answer?

Comment: This is probably a new question but using classes is not the right mechanics here. I suggest ids or data attributes